# Swapping adjacent elements of a linked list algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am practicing linked list programming questions in java, i have a working solution for the following question but cannot understand how it works.

I have commented beside each line what I think should be happening but obviously I haven't grasped how these are working yet, could someone please explain where my comments are wrong and how this solution is correct.(in my comments i use h for head, s for slow etc.)

Given a linked list, swap every two adjacent nodes and return its head.
Example:
Given 1->2->3->4, you should return the list as 2->1->4->3.

```
public Node s(Node head) {
    // 1(h)-2-3-4 passed in
    // if only 1 node or null node return it
    if (head == null || head.next == null) {
        return head;
    }

    Node slow = head.next;   // 1h-2s-3-4
    head.next = head.next.next; // 1h-3-4
    slow.next = head; // 2s-1h-3-4
    head = slow; // 2s/h-1-3-4
    Node parent = slow.next; // 1p-3-4
    slow = slow.next.next; // 3s-4

    while (slow != null && slow.next != null) {
        Node temp = slow.next;  // 4t-null
        slow.next = slow.next.next; // 3s-null
        temp.next = slow;    // 4t-3s-null
        parent.next = temp; // 1p-4-3
        parent = parent.next.next; // 3p=null
        slow = slow.next; // 4-null, loop ends cause next to slow is null
    }
    return head; // ( head = slow from earlier) 4-null 
}
```

Comment: Get a piece of paper and draw a picture of the linked list. Then work each step, drawing the updated picture each time. Or, cut out some squares on which you can draw "nodes", and move them around to follow the logic. Pictures and physical models often help you visualize things much better than a verbal or written explanation.

Comment: Yes I tried drawing on paper but my paper ends up the same as my comments, I am not sure how this piece of code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume a linked list of `A -> B -> C -> D`.

I've numbered the lines in your code to make it easier to talk about.

```
 1 public Node s(Node head) {
 2     // if only 1 node or null node return it
 3     if (head == null || head.next == null) {
 4         return head;
 5     }
 6 
 7     Node slow = head.next;
 8     head.next = head.next.next;
 9     slow.next = head;
10     head = slow;
11     Node parent = slow.next;
12     slow = slow.next.next;
13
14     while (slow != null && slow.next != null) {
15         Node temp = slow.next;
16         slow.next = slow.next.next;
17         temp.next = slow;
18         parent.next = temp;
19         parent = parent.next.next;
20         slow = slow.next;
21     }
22     return head;
23 }
```

At line 7, `slow` is made to point to node B. `head.next` is set to B's successor, C on line 8. On line 9, B points to A, and on line 10, `head` points to B. My comments show what happened.

```
 7     Node slow = head.next;      // slow = B
 8     head.next = head.next.next; // head.next = C
 9     slow.next = head;           // B.next = A (because head points to A)
10     head = slow;                // head = B
```

That code swapped the first two nodes. Your list now looks like this:

```
B -> A -> C -> D
```

Now the code gets kind of confusing, largely due to poor naming. `slow` currently points to B.

```
11     Node parent = slow.next;  // parent = A
12     slow = slow.next.next;    // slow = C
```

Remember that `slow` now points to C. Here's what happens next:

```
14     while (slow != null && slow.next != null) {
15         Node temp = slow.next;      // temp = D
16         slow.next = slow.next.next; // C.next = D.next (which is null)
17         temp.next = slow;           // D.next = C
18         parent.next = temp;         // A.next = D
```

At this point, nodes C and D have been swapped, and A points to D, as required. The list now looks like `B -> A -> D -> C`.

The final two lines in the loop just set things up for next time. Remember, that right now, `parent` points to A.

```
19         parent = parent.next.next;  // parent = C
20         slow = slow.next;           // slow = null
```

Looping back to the top, we see that `slow == null`, so the loop exits.

Whereas the code you posted works, it's unnecessarily confusing. There's no need to do a special swap of the first two nodes before going into the loop, and variable names could be more descriptive.

To swap two nodes, you have to make the second point to the first, and the first point to the second's successor. To do that, you have to save the second's successor before you overwrite it. For example, if you have `A -> B -> C` and you want `B -> A -> C`, then you have to do this, assuming that `head` points to A:

```
firstNode = head // firstNode points to A
secondNode = firstNode.next  // secondNode points to B
secondNodeSuccessor = secondNode.next // this points to C
secondNode.next = firstNode  // B now points to A
firstNode.next = secondNodeSuccessor  // A now points to C
head = secondNode  // and head points to B
```

At this point, `secondNodeSuccessor` is pointing to C, which is the next `firstNode`.

With that understanding of how to swap nodes, you can simplify the code quite a bit:

```
public Node s(Node head) {
    // if fewer than 2 nodes, return.
    if (head == null || head == null) {
        return head;
    }

    // we know that the new head will be the second node.
    Node firstNode = head;
    Node parentNode = null;

    while (firstNode != null && firstNode.next != null) {
        Node secondNode = firstNode.next;
        Node secondNodeSuccessor = secondNode.next;

        // swap the nodes
        secondNode.next = firstNode;
        firstNode.next = secondNodeSuccessor;

        if (parentNode != null) {
            // This links the previous node (the one right before
            // the two that we just swapped) to the swapped nodes.
            parentNode.next = secondNode;
        }
        // the new parent node is the last swapped node.
        parentNode = firstNode;
        firstNode = firstNode.next; // set up for next pair
    }

    return head.next;
}
```

Note the improvements here:

1. I eliminated the special-case swap of the first two nodes, which simplifies things by making every swap the same.
2. Meaningful variable names make it plain which node I'm referencing.
3. Eliminating the `.next.next` construction makes it easier to reason about the code, and also makes it easier to determine whether the code could potentially dereference a null.

Your debugger is a very useful tool for understanding how your code is working. If you were to single-step the code in your debugger, you could examine the variables and see how each line of code affects the state. If you don't know how to use your debugger, you should take the time right now to learn. It will save you *hours* of debugging, and also greatly increase your understanding of how code works.

Comment: Although your code doesn't seem to work, It only returns the 1st 2 elements in the list.

Comment: @MickO'Gorman See my update. I forgot to keep track of the previously swapped nodes so that I could link them together. That should work. Unfortunately, I don't have a Java environment up and running at the moment. If it doesn't work, you should be able to use my explanation to write your own code that does.

Comment: Even after the update of this question, the code doesn't work for all inputs, as can be proven by running it on LeetCode (https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs). Please see my answer for an alternative, working approach.

Answer (score 1):

In place of swapping nodes, we can swap data only that will be easy and will get the desired output.

```
 public Node s(Node head) { 
        if (head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }
        Node temp = head; 

        /* Traverse only till there are atleast 2 nodes left */
        while (temp != null && temp.next != null) { 

            /* Swap the data */
            int k = temp.data; 
            temp.data = temp.next.data; 
            temp.next.data = k; 
            temp = temp.next.next; 
        }
        return head;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the question states not to swap the data, this would be the much simpler approach though

Answer (score 0):

The other two solutions either don't match your requirements or provide wrong results for some inputs.

I propose an alternative approach that I have tested on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/) (if you want to test it yourself, please be sure to rename the Node type into ListNode).
I hope the comments I added to the code are clear enough. When in doubt, I suggest trying to execute this procedure in an interactive debugger.

```
public ListNode s(Node head) {
    // if the list is empty or it's a singleton, no node needs to be swapped
    if (head == null || head.next == null) {
        return head;
    }
  
    // first and second are the first and second node of the current pair to swap
    Node first = head;
    Node second = head.next;
    
    // parent is the node immediately before the current pair.
    // Initially, there is no such pair
    Node parent = null;
    
    // the updated list starts from the second node of the first pair
    head = second;
    
    // iterate until there is a valid pair to swap
    while (first != null && second != null) {
        // swap the two nodes of the current pair
        first.next = second.next;
        second.next = first;
        
        if (parent != null) {
            // attach the second element to the updated node of the previous pair
            parent.next = second;
        }
        
        // keep the invariant of parent valid: parent precedes the new pair to swap,
        // if such a pair exists
        parent = first;

        // advance the pointers of the first and second elements of the new pair to swap
        first = first.next;            
        second = (first == null) ? null : first.next;
    }
      
    return head;
}
```